# Docker swarm join as manager fails but succeeds as worker

Tags: docker, centos7, docker-swarm

I'm working on creating a 3 manager Docker Swarm using Docker CE 19.03 and three CentOS 7 machines.

I've installed docker via yum, enabled the service and started it.

I've created a firewalld 'service' and allowed (per docker docs):

- TCP port 2377 for cluster management communications
- TCP and UDP port 7946 for communication among nodes
- UDP port 4789 for overlay network traffic

I was able to init the swarm and join a worker. The third server I tried to join as a manager however and it failed with

> Error response from daemon: manager stopped: can't initialize raft node: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = could not connect to the prospective new cluster member using its advertised address: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded

So I backed out with `docker swarm leave` and tried to join as a worker. It succeeded no problem. Now why would I be failing to join as a manager but successfully joining as a worker?

I tried allowing 2376/tcp (per https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-linux-firewall-for-docker-swarm-on-centos-7) and disabling firewalld on the one manager to see if it was a firewall issue but I got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, lesson learned, *trust* the error messages.

I had applied my firewalld service template and forgotten to reload firewalld so the ports were not actually open. Apparently all those ports were not actually required to join as a worker but are as a manager.

I had noticed in my load balancer that my containers were frequently showing as failed on that host when they are not which led me to double check everything.

Answer (score 0):

There is a default time limit for swarm token.
You can create the token again to join

Comment: AFAIK, the time limit is one hour. I used the token immediately after generating it. In fact, the manager token was generated after the worker token so if anything, the worker token should have expired first. But you can see from the error message that the problem is not the token but the connection to the advertised address.

Comment: worker node time limit is far higher than manager. Anyway, why don't you just try getting token again with [docker swarm join-token manager]  and run the join command generated with the output. Ref: https://devopsdiaryblog.wordpress.com/2020/05/02/join-command/

Comment: The error message does not indicate a problem with the token, it indicates a problem with the connection. Anyways, I rotated the manager token and immediately tried to rejoin as a manager and it gave the same error. I rotated the worker token and was able to join as a worker with no issues.